# How to load into a database using dbisql from a shell script?

Tags: shell

I want to write a shell script so that I can schedule it.

```
dbisql -nogui -host host1 -port 2740 -c "uid=user;pwd=password"
LOAD TABLE dbname.tablename(col1,...,coln) USING CLIENT FILE ....
```

The main problem is that after the 1st command `dbisql`, the terminal becomes:

```
(dbname)>
```

If I run the 2nd command manually now, it works fine. But the shell script stops. How to proceed in this situation?

Note: I am familiar with expect but is that the only way to solve it? I would like to avoid expect if possible so generalize it for different databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a workaround for it. That is to create another (script.sql) file and copy the command load table to it and pass that script itself as an argument in same command.

```
dbisql -nogui -host host1 -port 2740 -c "uid=user;pwd=password" script.sql
```

To solve the original problem, just add quit. But I liked the above approach better because it is more generic.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue wherein when I run:

```
dbisql -datasource XXXX -q -c "uid=XXXX;pwd=XXXX" D:\script1.txt
```

it would not execute the SQL script written inside D:\script1.txt, I tried various combination and finally the below worked, I added a .exe and `-nogui` .   Hope this helps :)

```
dbisql.exe -nogui -datasource XXXX -q -c "uid=XXXX;pwd=XXXX" D:\script1.txt
```

Regards
Sunil Tauro